# Append data to SQL table from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have users entering in varying rows of data in an excel template, depending on the client data being entered this could be anything from 1 row to 400 rows spanning from columns B to L.

Is there a way in VBA to create a bulk insert into a SQL table where, as the user enters the data and then hits an upload button VBA can execute a macro to write back to the table?

I have done something similar before with a bulk insert on a .csv but was wondering if there is something a little more slick straight out of VBA code.

Many Thanks

Comment: You can use ADO for this - plenty of examples to be found via Google. E.g. http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_ado_insert.html If you need more specific help, then you need to add more detail, such as which DB you're using.

Comment: If it's only 400 rows at a clip, a bulk insert may be overkill, but you can certainly do all rows in a single transaction...  I would go one step further (from the link Tim sent) and add bind variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the link makes a lot of sense and is actually not too far off what I use to bring data in from SQL. My code so far is:

Comment: `Dim stSQL As String, sUMR As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ConnectionString As String

ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source=SE-WEB-0009;Initial catalog=London_DB;Integrated Security = SSPI;"

Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

sUMR = Sheets("Layer Details").Range("Y2").Value

stSQL = "EXEC [AC_Detail] '" & sUMR & "'"

With objConn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient 
    .Open ConnectionString
    Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
End With

objConn.Close

Set rst = Nothing

Set objConn = Nothing`

Comment: I guess the piece I'm struggling with is the actual Insert statement back to my Table in SQL, which would fall in the `stSQL = EXEC` part picking up data from columns B to L with varying rows. How do I capture that?

Comment: If you want to add code then it's best to edit your question and add it there: code in comments is difficult to read and most people here won't bother.